# ftp from device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, ftp

When i send a .txt file via ftp on the simulator it works fine. but when i send it from the device, the .txt file gets send, put not the contents of it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You asked a similar question the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312951/sending-txt-file-to-ftp) (and didn't mark an answer.)

How are you trying to upload the file via FTP?  Please show us some code.

As I said in my answer to your other question, an easy way to upload a txt file via ftp would be to use some pre-canned FTP library.  This one seems to be good, and they have examples on their web page of how to upload files with just a few lines of code:

http://code.google.com/p/s7ftprequest/